# Скрыть div если value в нем 0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Привет!

Есть блок расчета, результат из него выводится в Html (span):

```
<div class="res">Вес одного <span id="result3"></span></div>
<div class="res">Общий вес <span id="result4"></span></div>
<div class="res">Сумма <span id="result5"></span></div>
```

Как скрыть `div`, если передаваемое в `#result` число: 0 или NaN ?

Comment: тоесть если `id` дива равно чтото типа `result0` `resultNaN` ?

Comment: Да, если  #result.value (я так понимаю это в value идет) ==0 или NaN

Comment: а как ети `id` туда попадают ? можно конечно взять все дивы где  `id` начинается на `result` и в цикле их обработать, но помоему будет проще сделать это на етапе установки этих `id`

Comment: `id` заданы в html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то реализовать можно как-то так:

```js
/**
 * Если значение внутри #result
 */
let block_array = document.querySelectorAll(".res");
for (let i = 0; i < block_array.length; i++) {
  let child = block_array[i].lastChild;
  let value = +child.innerHTML;

  if (value == 0 || isNaN(value)) {
    block_array[i].classList.add("none");
  } else if (value > 0) {
    block_array[i].classList.remove("none");
  }
}
```

```css
.none {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="res">Вес одного <span id="result0">0</span></div>
<div class="res">Общий вес <span id="result4">4</span></div>
<div class="res">Сумма <span id="resultNaN">NaN</span></div>
```

```js
/**
 * Если идет строго по ID
 **/
let block_array_ = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=result]");
for (let i = 0; i < block_array_.length; i++) {
  let id_value = block_array_[i].getAttribute("id").substr(6);
  if (id_value == 0 || isNaN(id_value)) {
    block_array_[i].parentNode.classList.add("none");
  }
}
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="res">Вес одного <span id="result3">3</span></div>
<div class="res">Общий вес <span id="result4">4</span></div>
<div class="res">Сумма <span id="result0">0</span></div>
```

Comment: /*Если значение внутри #result*/ Работает, но,подскажите, как удалить `.none` если `value` станет `>0` ?

Comment: @riyga добавил в ответ

Comment: спасибо, всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ, получаем все елементы с атрибутом `id` который начинается на `result` (селектор `[id^="result"]`), пробегаемся по ним, смотрим на что там заканчивается `id` , делаем выводы, скрываем нужные елементы.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="result"]');
    divs.forEach(function(div) {
      var id = +div.id.substring(6);
      if (isNaN(id) || id <= 0) {
        div.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.res {
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="res"><span id="result3">3</span></div>
<div class="res"><span id="result4">4</span></div>
<div class="res"><span id="result5">5</span></div>
<div class="res"><span id="result0">0</span></div>
<div class="res"><span id="result-1">-1</span></div>
<div class="res"><span id="resultNaN">NaN</span></div>

<button id="btn">do the magic</button>
```

Comment: Как я понял ваш код определяет что скрывать по имени (скрыть если `#result***`, верно? Но мне нужно чтобы `div[res]` скрывался по значению приходящему в `#result` (оно,как я понимаю, является `value` у `#result`) 0 или NaN.

Comment: смотрите мой код смотрит на само значение `id`, если вам надо смотреть не на `id`, а на текст в спане, то там вверху есть ответ который ето решает.